# Is there a way to check for every FormControl validity in one line?

Tags: angular, typescript

I wanted to understand if there was an existing method allowing us to check all formControls validity at once.

Example:

```
// we have the following
hello = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
world = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
```

Instead of writing this:

```
// check validity
if (this.hello.invalid || this.world.invalid) {
    return;
}
```

Is there a own line function? This is just two form controls, but let's say you have 10 of them, it can become rather cumbersome....

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to use formgroup and you can check the validity by this.form.valid.

Comment: these docs might help you [reeactive-forms-angular](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and [formGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check all the controls validity together using `form.valid`

Try like this:

```
if(this.myForm.valid) {
}
```